# Including a file in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: grails-2.0

I am porting AXIS 2 SOAP webservice  to an existing grails 2.4.4 project.

It works flawlessly when run from the IDE but not fram a WAR.

I have tracked this down to addresing.mar NOT being copied to the WEB-INF lib directory. If I copy this file myself then ever thing works fine.

We are using Jenkins for CI and using the Grails plugin to do the compilation of and packaging of the WAR file.

This does not include the addresing.mar file. Also when running the Grails war command it is not included.

I have tried many way to get this to be included. The AXIS plug in just wrecks the compile to teh extent that it is unusable.

I have just spent 2 days googling and tried ever thing I can find in just about every combination.

We are now getting to the point we we are considering post processing the war file and adding the addresing.mar file directly.

Though that will work it would not help my understanding of what I am doing wrong!

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your file inside the /src file. Grails autowires external libraries when saved inside this folder.

Note: This is only applicable to Grails versions running less than 3.x.x

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about AXIS 2 SOAP and the mentioned `addressing.mar` file but if it's available in the project while building the war file you could use the `grails.war.resources` parameter in `BuildConfig.groovy` and simply copy it into the lib directory in the following way:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
   copy(file: "path/to/addressing.mar", todir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/")
}
```

more info about [grails.war.resources](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.5/guide/deployment.html) in the manual